# Webpack HtmlWebpackPlugin добавляет скрипты после каждого билда

Tags: javascript, webpack

Использую Webpack "2.4.1", после каждого билда добавляются скрипты в index.html, без удаления предыдущих.
В чем может быть проблема?
Конфиг:

```js
"use strict";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
//var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
//var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: "./app/main.ts",
        polyfills: "./app/polyfills.ts",
    },
    output: {
        filename: "./dist/[name].js",
        sourceMapFilename: '[file].map',
        chunkFilename: './dist/[id].chunk.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loaders: ['ts-loader?' + JSON.stringify({
                    configFileName: 'tsconfig.json'
                }),
                'angular-router-loader'],
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            /* Embed files. */
            {
                test: /\.(html|css)$/,
                loader: 'raw-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: [ 'polyfills']
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            hash: true,
            template: './index.html'
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
    },
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map'
};
```

Comment: Мне кажется вы просто один и тот же index.html читаете и туда же записываете. А должно быть иначе, браться исходный файл прогоняться через плагин, и появляться новый, например в `./dist/index.html`

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, хм, да, вы правы.Вариантов с апдейтом, а не с копированием нет?

Comment: Маловероятно что они есть, плагин просто добавляет исходники в загрузку на страницу, зачем его усложнять. Свою цель он выполняет. Можете написать для себя :) На самом деле не сложно, нужно лишь проверять приходящий скомпиленный js файл, на наличие его на странице, просто как поиск по тексту. Если он есть то ничего не делать, если нет, то добавить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь надо смотреть на вашу структуру проекта. Полагаю, вам надо положить исходники куда-нибудь в `./src`, а `./dist` оставить под сборку. Далее, укажите `output.path`, в вашем случае это `dist`, т.е. примерно так:

```
output: {
    path: 'dist',
    filename: '[name].js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[file].map',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
},
```